# Trying to place buttons over a view in xcode

Tags: ios, button, user-interface, uiview, subview

I am trying to create buttons that stay over a view so that the view is displayed under then.
So it should be all about positioning the buttons maybe? I tried moving the buttons over the view label but it didn't work because they are not displayed.

Then what I did was to try dragging out a second view and I made that second view a subview of the first one. I put the buttons in it but when I run the application I only see the superview and the subview-the one with the buttons isn't displayed and I can't figure out why.

I am creating everything non-programatically and just by dragging.
Do you happen to know how I can achieve the result?

Thanks.

Comment: if the views are on same hierarchy then view added later will be shown above the first one

Comment: Give a title to the button and see if it appears. Also in the left side of xib, drag the button to the bottom of the list

Comment: [parentView bringSubviewToFront:ButtonView];

Comment: adnan the view that I added later isn't showing above the first